# How to use Python to convert rows to columns in an excel (.xls) file that require the extraction of keywords?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

Let's say I have an excel file as below:

[image]

If you are not able to view the image link, the excel file is basically like this:

```
Name       XXX
Age        XXX
Gender     XXX
Job        XXX
Location   XXX
...        ...
...        ...
```

(Repeat the list of "Name, Age, Gender, Job, Location".) *There are at least 1000 or more lists in the file.* "XXX" represent the content correspond to each field of the list.

I searched online about row-to-column conversion, and I found the paste function called 'transpose' within the excel. However, it is very simple as it converts all the rows into columns.

What I want to do is to **have only 5 columns**, with column names of Name, Age, Gender, Job and Location.

Comment: Is all the info filled in for each person (i.e. does each person have a Name, Age, Gender, Job, and Location)? If not, how is missing data handled?

Comment: Hi Robert. Yes, the information for each person is filled in.

Comment: New to Python, but you use Python2.7? [You might want to reconsider](https://pythonclock.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
dfs = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', sheet_name=None,header=None)
tester=dfs['Sheet1'].values.tolist()
keys = list(zip(*tester))[0]
seen = set()
seen_add = seen.add
keysu= [x for x in keys if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
values = list(zip(*tester))[1]
a = np.array(values).reshape(int(len(values)/len(keysu)),len(keysu))
list1=[keysu]
for i in a:
    list1.append(list(i))
df=pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx',index=False,header=False)
```

> input.xlsx

[image]

> Output.xlsx

[image]